# Random encryption of string in C#

Tags: c#, string, encryption

I wanted to encrypt a string value with this method.

```
    public string EncryptString(string inputString)
    {

       MemoryStream memStream = null;

        try
        {
            byte[] key = { };
            byte[] IV = { 12, 21, 43, 17, 57, 35, 67, 27 };
            string encryptKey = "aXb2uy4z";
            key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptKey);
            byte[] byteInput = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString);
            DESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            memStream = new MemoryStream();
            ICryptoTransform transform = provider.CreateEncryptor(key, IV);
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cryptoStream.Write(byteInput, 0, byteInput.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(memStream.ToArray());
    }
```

The thing I want to do is that the encrypted string will always be random. Any one know how to do it? Please help.

Comment: How do you want to decrypt after then ?

Comment: What do you mean by random? If you encrypt the same string twice in a row, would you get two different answers? Then what good is that?

Comment: use rijndael encryption with a Salt. it will make sure your encrypted string is always different.

Comment: You may append *random noise* to the string before encryption: `"abc"` -> `abc\01g6$...`. When decrypted just cut off the noise

Comment: or you can add some random cipher key to your characters randomly, but you have to keep your cipher key with your encrypted string in a sequential manner so that you can decrypt them again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < r.Next(100); i++) sb.Append((char)r.Next(65, 255));
string s = sb.ToString();
```

Make sure you store the string or you won't be able to decrypt

Answer (score 0):

If you want some random value for your encryption (for example a salt value, to make the usage of rainbow tables impossible), i always use Guids. They are unique and "random".

Be sure to keep your salt, because you will need it later, for example, if you want to proof wether a password is correct:

```
PASSWORD + SALT --encryption--> Hash
```

If you forget the salt, you will not be able to build the same Hash again.

If you want to encrypt passwords, you algorithm is not very useful. I would take the following code-snippet from SO: [sha-256 hash in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17001289/2630261)

Just be sure, that you pass `password + hash` to the method, to get your encrypted value with some random "touch".