# How to convert hash function result to string representation properly?

Tags: c#, .net

I attempting to convert hash to string

[image]
but it returns incorrect string. What am i doing wrong?

for example, if i generate hash on quickhash.com it returns correct string
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999361/obtain-sha-256-string-of-a-string/17001289#17001289

Comment: Check the documentation [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a(v=vs.110).aspx) on the bottom

Comment: @DmitryBychenko good duplicate, I think you should vote to re-open that other question as well. The question itself is not that great, but together with the answer it makes perfect sense.