# The right way to compare hashed passwords

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I have a field in my database which is binary(32) for storing SHA-256 passwords. Since MSSQL store the hash in upper case and with 0x prefix, I've done this:

```
public static string getHashSha256(string text)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        SHA256Managed hashstring = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] hash = hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);
        string hashString = string.Empty;
        foreach (byte x in hash)
        {
            hashString += String.Format("{0:x2}",  x);
        }
        return "0x" + hashString.ToUpper();
    }
```

Is this acceptable or there is a more appropriate way to do this?

Comment: You should be using a "salt". The salt should change every time the user changes their password. If you don't use a salt, everybody with the same password will have the same hash, which we've [already seen](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/04/anatomy-of-a-password-disaster-adobes-giant-sized-cryptographic-blunder/) is a bad idea, and leaves compromised hashes vulnerable to dictionary attacks.

Comment: As for your comparison, if you have both values as byte arrays, you can use `.SequenceEqual()`.

Comment: If I use .SequenceEqual(), there will be no need for returning the hash with `0x` prefix and `.ToUpper()`?

Comment: "Since MSSQL store the hash in upper case and with 0x prefix" - that's not so. Column type in binary, so it stores it as binary, not as any string. So you should retrieve it from database as `byte[]` and compare accordingly. No need to involve strings anywhere in the process.

Comment: @Evk I see so If I got this right, It's upper case because for example the A is `01000001` and not `01100001` (a) in binary?

Comment: String you see is representation for display. Most likely it's hex. It's not stored like that and  there is no reason for you to work with it in such form.

Comment: Even in SQL when I select from the table, It's just a representation? It looks like it. I just made the function above so It return byte and then compare it like you said and when I try to display that, I get XX-XX-XX-XX etc. and when I compare it to the database, the comparaison is successful, even though the database is not displaying the database values have no dashes.

Comment: You have to **Dispose** `SHA256Managed` instance since it implements `IDisposable`, otherwise you'll get resource leakage; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999361/obtain-sha-256-string-of-a-string/17001289#17001289

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I should add `hash.Dispose()` just before the return?

Comment: @Abdou: try standard pattern: `using (SHA256Managed hashstring = new SHA256Managed()) {...return ...}`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yeah I just managed to understand that `using` does the dispose for you. Well, we learn every day :) Thanks for help man

Answer (score -1):

```
public static string ConvertToHash(string dataToComputeHash)
    {
        var hash = "";
        try
        {
            var keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);
            using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
            {
                hmacsha256.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(dataToComputeHash));
                hash = ByteToString(hmacsha256.Hash);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return hash;
    }
```

Comment: Side note: please, never do/recommend this `catch (Exception ex) { }` - *ignoring all the exceptions*. We may ignore only some errors, and, francly speaking, I can' see any reason to ignore either `ArgumentNullException` or `ObjectDisposedException`: we should not *hide* the problem in the code.