# C# Return Value SHA256Managed is NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sha256

I have a class where it is responsible for generating a hash according to what I send to it. However, the return of the `SHA256Managed.Create(text)` method is always returning `null`.

The following is my code:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace Autenticacao_no_ASP_.NET_MVC.Utils
{
    public class Hash
    {
        public static string GerarHash(string texto)
        {
            SHA256 sha256 = SHA256Managed.Create(texto);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(texto);
            byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(bytes);
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
            {
                result.Append(hash[i].ToString("X"));
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

> **sha256** which is being returned null.

Comment: Is FIPS mode active?

Comment: Where can I check this?

Comment: Good question.  Is this ASP.NET Core?

Comment: No. It's ASP.NET MVC 4

Comment: What string is in `texto`?

Comment: I pass the parameter to the class, like this: `Hash.GerarHash(cadastroUsuarioViewModels.Senha)`

Comment: OK, the string that you pass to Create() can be one of: `SHA256Managed`, `SHA256Cng`, `SHA256CryptoServiceProvider`.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256.create?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: `SHA256Managed.Create(texto)`  is wrong.  You're telling it the name of the algorithm to use here, but `texto` isn't the name of an algorithm.

Comment: Why are you using `SHA256.Create(string)` to create the algorithm instance.  Why not just new up an `SHA256Managed` or use `SHA256.Create()`.  My guess is that you are specifying the algorithm in the string incorrectly

Comment: The "text" would be the parameter I get in the Hash class to then generate it.

Comment: Yeah, you might try just removing `texto` from your `Create()` call.

Comment: If you really want to be able to pick the algorithm using a string like that, use an `enum` to make it _"pick from list"_ (and then calling `.ToString()` on the enum

Comment: Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256.create?view=netframework-4.7.2.  SHA256Managed doesn't actually have a `Create()` method; it's getting that from the base class, which is SHA256.  The create method overload you're using requires you to specify the algorithm you want.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for the help.

The problem was this same variable within `SHA256Managed.Create(texto)`. The correct one was just `SHA256Managed.Create()`.

Thank you! Happy New Year to all!

Comment: It's worth noting that `SHA256Managed.Create()` may not create an `SHA256Managed` at all.  You are really calling `SHA256.Create()`, and it creates an algorithm as it sees fit (it may create the `Cng` version or the `CryptoServiceProvider` version.  If you really want an `SHA256Managed`, just new it up

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999361/obtain-sha-256-string-of-a-string/17001289#17001289

Answer (score 3):

Preferred way to create SHA256 (use SHA256 to pick implementation):

```
SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create();
```

Parameter of `Create` is name of algorithm - you don't really need to pass one unless you use base class to pick which one to use. To fix you code remove or use correct parameter:

```
SHA256 sha256 = SHA256Managed.Create();
```

or

```
SHA256 sha256 = SHA256Managed.Create("SHA256");
```

Note that both calls actually are implemented by base `SHA256` class and first just pick "default" implementation.

See [SHA256.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256.create?view=netframework-4.7.2) for reference.

Comment: Yes, it was happening like this: SHA256Managed.Create (text) and the correct one was just SHA256Managed.Create ().

Thank you! Happy New Year to all!