# password hashing sha256 in c#

Tags: c#, sha256

I had created a WinForms application with a login system in vs 2019, and now I want to hash the password entered by the user before storing it in the database. But it will exist three errors :

Code:

```
public static string getHash(string source)
    {
        using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
        {
            string hash = getsha256Hash(sha256Hash, source);
            return getsha256Hash(sha256Hash, source);
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999361/obtain-sha-256-string-of-a-string/17001289#17001289

Comment: `using System.Security.Cryptography;` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256?view=net-6.0

Comment: "But it will exist three errors" - what errors? Why are you computing the hash twice? And what does the `getsha256Hash` method look like? Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for a guide on how to write good Stack Overflow questions - and I'd strong advise you to start following normal .NET naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
    
private static string GenerateHash(string toHash)
{
    var crypt = new SHA256Managed();
    string hash = String.Empty;
    byte[] crypto = crypt.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toHash));
    foreach (byte theByte in crypto)
    {
        hash += theByte.ToString("x2");
    }
    return hash;
}
```

I once solved this problem like this)).

Comment: Do not forget to *dispose* `crypt`, e.g. `using var crypt = new SHA256Managed();`