# Create a signature using ES256

Tags: digital-signature, azure-keyvault

I am trying the [sign operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/sign/sign?source=recommendations&tabs=HTTP) using an EC Key that I've created in Azure Key Vault.

The process should be straight forward:
A post request like this
`POST {vaultBaseUrl}/keys/{key-name}/{key-version}/sign?api-version=7.4`
that will include a JSON string in the body of the request like this one:

```
{
  "alg": "ES256",
  "value": "eyJhbGciOiAiRVMyNTYifQ.eyJrZXlBIjoidmFsdWUxIiwia2V5QiI6InZhbHVlMiIsImtleUMiOiAidmFsdWUzIn0"
}
```

I'm encoding the value using C#:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

string header = "{\"alg\": \"ES256\"}";
string payload = "{\"keyA\":\"value1\",\"keyB\":\"value2\",\"keyC\": \"value3\"}";
var abc = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(header) + "." + Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(payload);
```

I get a 400 Bad Request with the following message

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadParameter",
        "message": "Content of 'value' is not base64url.\r\nProperty 'value' is required.\r\n"
    }
}
```

I've removed the first part that includes the algorithm, and I kept only the payload part, because the algorithm it's passed in the body of the request and I assumed that it's not needed, and I've tried to use the following body instead:

```
{
  "alg": "ES256",
  "value": "eyJrZXlBIjoidmFsdWUxIiwia2V5QiI6InZhbHVlMiIsImtleUMiOiAidmFsdWUzIn0"
}
```

But I also get a 400 Bad Request with the following message

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadParameter",
        "message": "Invalid length of 'value': 50 bytes. ES256 requires 32 bytes, encoded with base64url."
    }
}
```

Definitely I am not passing the correct value in the body of the request, but I cannot figure it out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: The key I've created in the KeyVault is a Key type: EC and Elliptic curve name: P-256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I did wrong. In the body of the request, the value parameter expects a digest, not the payload.
This is what I did (using Samuel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69168798/7266900)):

```
string HashWithSHA256(string value)
{
    using var hash = SHA256.Create();
    var byteArray = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
    return Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(byteArray);
}
string digest = HashWithSHA256(payload);
```

Now the body in the request looks like this:

```
{
    "alg":"ES256",
    "value":"cIbyvtAdTF7CYYKAtSJX8UPGRwF20R4nry9Di1NTke4"
}
```

I've tried this, with several payloads, and I was able to obtain the signature and to verify it (using the [verify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/verify/verify?tabs=HTTP) REST API operation). The verify operation always returns:

```
{
    "value": true
}
```